# Decorators are not supported in Babel 6.x + Webpack 2 + React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-2

I am using **transform-decorators-legacy** and I am still getting the error below. The project is based off of react-redux-universal-hot-example, but expanded upon. I believe the issue is either in .babelrc or my webpack config.

I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

**Error**: "BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Decorators are not officially supported yet in 6.x pending a proposal update."

```
> 12 | export default class ReportSubscriptionSelector extends Component {
```

**Package.json**: (Removed some code that was unnessesary) Aware of some issues here.

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.6.3",
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.6.1",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.7.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.19",
    "bootstrap-sass-loader": "^1.0.10",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.15",
    "client-sessions": "^0.7.0",
    "compression": "^1.6.0",
    "concurrently": "^0.1.1",
    "eslint": "1.10.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "0.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.5.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-session": "^1.12.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "history": "^2.0.1",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^1.0.3",
    "http-proxy": "^1.12.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "invariant": "^2.2.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ladda": "^0.9.8",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash.capitalize": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash.clone": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.difference": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.filter": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash.forown": "^3.0.2",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash.merge": "^3.3.2",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.partition": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.pick": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.pluck": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash.some": "^3.2.3",
    "lodash.union": "^3.1.0",
    "lru-memoize": "^1.0.0",
    "map-props": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.14.2",
    "moment": "^2.10",
    "multireducer": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "normalizr": "^2.0.0",
    "piping": "^0.3.0",
    "pretty-error": "^1.2.0",
    "query-string": "^3.0.0",
    "re-notif": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-datagrid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-date-range": "^0.9.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-document-meta": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "react-immutable-render-mixin": "^0.9.0",
    "react-inline-css": "^2.0.0",
    "react-ladda": "FoxxMD/react-ladda#2989787",
    "react-loader-advanced": "^0.7.0",
    "react-overlays": "^0.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.20.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-beta8",
    "react-spinkit": "^1.1.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "react-toastr": "2.8.0",
    "recompose": "^0.14.5",
    "redbox-react": "^1.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-async-connect": "^1.0.0-rc2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.0-beta-3",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.0-beta-3",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.0-beta-3",
    "redux-form": "^3.0.12",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^2.3.1",
    "redux-router": "^1.0.0-beta7",
    "redux-storage": "^1.4.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "reselect": "^2.2.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "restler": "^3.4.0",
    "scroll-behavior": "^0.3.2",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.1.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "sifter": "^0.4.5",
    "sinon": "^1.17.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.3.7",
    "superagent": "^1.4.0",
    "timekeeper": "0.0.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "validator": "^4.5.0",
    "warning": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-isomorphic-tools": "^2.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-typecheck": "^3.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "better-npm-run": "^0.0.8",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.19",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.3.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.5",
    "chai": "^3.3.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.15",
    "concurrently": "^0.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "eslint": "1.10.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "0.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.5.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.10",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "^2.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "react-a11y": "^0.2.6",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.8",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redbox-react": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-async-connect": "^1.0.0-rc2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.0.0-beta-3",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.0-beta-3",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.0-beta-3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "strip-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-runtime",
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-react-display-name"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "typecheck",
        [
          "react-transform",
          {
            "transforms": [
              {
                "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                "imports": ["react"],
                "locals": ["module"]
              },
              {
                "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                "imports": [
                  "react",
                  "redbox-react"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
```

}

**dev.config.js**: (webpack.config for dev)

```
require('babel-polyfill');

// Webpack config for development
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/dist');
var host = (process.env.HOST || 'localhost');
var port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) + 1 || 3001;
var themePath = path.join(__dirname, '../src/theme');

// https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools
var WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = require('webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin');
var webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(require('./webpack-isomorphic-tools'));

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var babelrcObject = {};

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

try {
  babelrcObject = JSON.parse(babelrc);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
  console.error(err);
}

var babelrcObjectDevelopment = babelrcObject.env && babelrcObject.env.development || {};
var babelLoaderQuery = Object.assign({}, babelrcObject, babelrcObjectDevelopment);
delete babelLoaderQuery.env;

babelLoaderQuery.plugins = babelLoaderQuery.plugins || [];
for (var i = 0; i < babelLoaderQuery.plugins.length; ++i) {
  var plugin = babelLoaderQuery.plugins[i];
  if (Array.isArray(plugin) && plugin[0] === 'react-transform') {
    reactTransform = plugin;
  }
}

if (!reactTransform) {
  reactTransform = ['react-transform', { transforms: [] }];
  babelLoaderQuery.plugins.push(reactTransform);
}

if (!reactTransform[1] || !reactTransform[1].transforms) {
  reactTransform[1] = Object.assign({}, reactTransform[1], { transforms: [] });
}

// make sure react-transform-hmr is enabled
reactTransform[1].transforms.push({
  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
  imports: ['react'],
  locals: ['module']
});

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://' + host + ':' + port + '/__webpack_hmr',
      'font-awesome-webpack!./src/theme/font-awesome.config.js',
      `bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader?extractStyles&configFilePath=${themePath}/bs3.yml!bootstrap-loader/no-op.js`,
      './src/client.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: JSON.stringify(babelLoaderQuery)
          },
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader'
          }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: '2',
              sourceMap: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              outputStyle: 'expanded',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: '2',
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              outputStyle: 'expanded',
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: '10000',
              mimeType: 'application/font-woff'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: '10000',
              mimeType: 'application/octet-stream'
            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: '10000',
              mimeType: 'image/svg+xml'
            }
          }]
      },
      {
        test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: '10240'
          }
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.json', '.js', 'jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      Tether: "tether",
      "window.Tether": "tether",
      Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
      Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
      Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
      Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
      Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
      Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
      Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
      Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
      Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
      Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
      Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
    }),
    // css files from the extract-text-plugin loader
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].css', allChunks: true }),
    // hot reload
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: true  // <-------- DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
    }),
    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.development()
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include the plugin also in `dev.config.js`

```
options: {
   plugins: [ 'transform-decorators-legacy' ]
}
```